# What does request.POST.get method return in Django?

Tags: django

What does **request.POST.get("a")** return while ***"a"*** is the reference to following html

```
label for = "a">ADDED ITEMS:</label>
<input hidden type="number" name="a" id="a">
```

def myfunc():

```
if request.method == "POST":
    a = request.POST.get("a");
    obj = TransferedItems(item_id = a);
    obj.save();
    return HttpResponse("sent")
else:
    return HttpResponse("form submission failed")
```

I am new at Django and I am unable to find what does request.POST.get return. Please guide me on my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's `request.POST` [is a dictionary-like object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST), which means that its `get()` method behaves exactly like [the regular `dict`'s `get()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

> `get(key[, default])`
>
> Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never raises a KeyError.

So, to answer your question, `request.POST.get("a")` either returns the value of `a`, which is always a string (although it can be an empty string!) or the value `None`. The following code tests which of these possibilities is the case:

```py
a = request.POST.get("a")

if a is None:
    return HttpResponseBadRequest("No key `a` present in POST data")

if a == "":
    return HttpResponseBadRequest("Empty string supplied for `a` in POST data")

TransferedItems.objects.create(item_id = a)

return HttpResponse("sent")
```

Answer (score 1):

It returns the value of the field with name `a` that your sending from HTML. If the value doesn't exists, it returns `None`

Comment: Thanks! How can I check it? I am writing print(a) but it does not show me anything in console.

Comment: It means that field with name `a` is not being send from the HTML client. Can you re-check your form?

Comment: `print(a)` will print the value in the terminal where your server is running, and not in the browser console.